# Need Help in putting image into javascript snake

Tags: javascript, html, image

im new to writing scripts, im making informatics project,and i need help with putting image into the background to this:

```
<canvas id="gc" width="2137" height="2137"></canvas>

<script>
window.onload=function() {
    canv=document.getElementById("gc");
    ctx=canv.getContext("2d");
    document.addEventListener("keydown",keyPush);
    setInterval(game,1000/15);
}
px=py=5;
gs=tc=47;
ax=ay=25;
xv=yv=0;
trail=[];
tail = 5;
function game() {
    px+=xv;
    py+=yv;
    if(px<0) {
        px= tc-1;
    }
    if(px>tc-1) {
        px= 0;
    }
    if(py<0) {
        py= tc-1;
    }
    if(py>tc-1) {
        py= 0;
    }
    ctx.fillStyle="black";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canv.width,canv.height);

    ctx.fillStyle="lime";
    for(var i=0;i<trail.length;i++) {
        ctx.fillRect(trail[i].x*gs,trail[i].y*gs,gs-2,gs-2);
        if(trail[i].x==px && trail[i].y==py) {
            tail = 5;
        }
    }
    trail.push({x:px,y:py});
    while(trail.length>tail) {
    trail.shift();
    }

    if(ax==px && ay==py) {
        tail++;
        ax=Math.floor(Math.random()*tc);
        ay=Math.floor(Math.random()*tc);
    }
    ctx.fillStyle="red";
    ctx.fillRect(ax*gs,ay*gs,gs-2,gs-2);
}
function keyPush(evt) {
    switch(evt.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            xv=-1;yv=0;
            break;
        case 38:
            xv=0;yv=-1;
            break;
        case 39:
            xv=1;yv=0;
            break;
        case 40:
            xv=0;yv=1;
            break;
    }
}
</script>
```

this is the background and the only thing i can do with it is change colors.

```
ctx.fillStyle="black";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canv.width,canv.height);
```

i tried using everything, but nothing worked.

Comment: please give it a better title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to put image into canvas game, put preloaded image element in each loop, inside of/after background clearing:

```js
var img;
window.onload=function() {
    canv=document.getElementById("gc");
    ctx=canv.getContext("2d");
    document.addEventListener("keydown",keyPush);
    
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
    
    
    setInterval(game,1000/15);
   };
   img.src = 'http://loremflickr.com/g/2137/2137/cat';
  
    
}
px=py=5;
gs=tc=47;
ax=ay=25;
xv=yv=0;
trail=[];
tail = 5;
function game() {
    px+=xv;
    py+=yv;
    if(px<0) {
        px= tc-1;
    }
    if(px>tc-1) {
        px= 0;
    }
    if(py<0) {
        py= tc-1;
    }
    if(py>tc-1) {
        py= 0;
    }
    ctx.fillStyle="black";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canv.width,canv.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,canv.width,canv.height);

    ctx.fillStyle="lime";
    for(var i=0;i<trail.length;i++) {
        ctx.fillRect(trail[i].x*gs,trail[i].y*gs,gs-2,gs-2);
        if(trail[i].x==px && trail[i].y==py) {
            tail = 5;
        }
    }
    trail.push({x:px,y:py});
    while(trail.length>tail) {
    trail.shift();
    }

    if(ax==px && ay==py) {
        tail++;
        ax=Math.floor(Math.random()*tc);
        ay=Math.floor(Math.random()*tc);
    }
    ctx.fillStyle="red";
    ctx.fillRect(ax*gs,ay*gs,gs-2,gs-2);
}
function keyPush(evt) {
    switch(evt.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            xv=-1;yv=0;
            break;
        case 38:
            xv=0;yv=-1;
            break;
        case 39:
            xv=1;yv=0;
            break;
        case 40:
            xv=0;yv=1;
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gc" width="2137" height="2137"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set background image to the canvas using css ? Here is a working example.

```css
#gc{
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/300x300?text=snake+backgroun');
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gc" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: You forgot the "d" in background ;)